# Their is any way to detect my app goes in background state or killed when i'm on any screen of my app in Flutter

Tags: flutter

Their is any way to detect my app goes in background state or killed when i'm on any screen of my app in Flutter instead of using WidgetsBindingObserver on every screen. i have update offline status on firebase server when app is minimized or killed and when it relaunched then it will be online. I am able to identify this on a particular screen but i have to handle it on every screen, so that we can handle on every screen approach is wrong can their is any other way?.

Comment: and cannot it work if you setup the observer only on the first, starting `Route`?

Comment: pskink sir, my first screen is splash and i'm using pushReplacement() this will remove splash from stack, so think it will not work. but i will try with it once and let you know what is the update.

Comment: so try it with the first, not temporary `Route`, btw why yoe ever use any "splash" screens if you can use `FutureBuilder`?